# Firestore rules - Why is adding an OR statement in a rule returning false when rule passes without the OR statement?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore rule that passes until I add an OR statement. Shouldn't this still pass regardless of whether the right side is true or false?

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)/users/$(request.auth.uid)) 
|| hasRole(['Super', 'Manager', 'Tester']);
```

If I leave out the || hasRole(['Super', 'Manager', 'Tester']); the rule passes/allows data access.

Is this related to the function or am I missing something with Or statements in firestore rules?

```
function hasRole(roles) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/Seva%20Development/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny(roles);
}
```

companies/company/users/userId has a number of fields, one of which is roles. Roles is an array of string (for example: ["Admin", "Manager", "Tester"]).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data type and contents of `data.roles` in the document you're expecting it to check.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you aren't using your variables correctly in `hasRole` and `data` should be called after the `get`. `hasRole` should be:

```
function hasRole(roles) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)/users/$(userId)).data.roles.hasAny(roles);
}
```

Comment: I had tried to leave out the path variables to simplify, but I've updated the function to have those as they are, and I've edited it to have data after the get is called, but it still denies permission.

Comment: What type of request are you making? `get` or `list`? If `list`, then I don't think your rules will work, because Firestore enforces rules that don't get executed for each document in the result set. (i.e. yours won't work because you nested `users` under each document.)

Comment: It's a get request. I don't use list requests in this application. Even double checked that the simulator is checking a get request only.